# how to add date picker in activescaffold with rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, activescaffold

At https://github.com/activescaffold/active_scaffold/wiki/API:-Column

It recommends to install a plugin: https://github.com/scambra/unobtrusive_date_picker

Now I am using rails4 so can't really install a plugin as it says rails 4 has removed support for plugins at: http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/rails-plugin-reaches-end-of-life-rails-4-countdown-to-2013

Please suggest how I can turn all the date fields to data pickers in activescaffold. Simpler the better.

Thanks

EDIT: Adding response to a comment:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.4)
2.1.1 :001 > ActiveScaffold.exclude_bridges.exclude? :date_picker
 => true 
2.1.1 :002 > ActiveScaffold::Bridges::DatePicker.install?
 => true 
2.1.1 :003 > ActiveScaffold::Bridges::DatePicker.jquery_ui_included?
 => true 
2.1.1 :004 > Jquery.const_defined?('Ui')
 => false 
2.1.1 :005 > 
2.1.1 :007 > Admin::PlansController.active_scaffold_config.columns[:plan_start].form_ui
 => :date_picker
```

Answer (score 0):

Date Picker Bridge is now in active scaffold core. Active Scaffold will automatically detect that Date Picker is installed, and will make use it.

You just need to include jQuery and jQueryUI as dependencies. 
It can be added via jquery-ui-rails gem is on your gemset, activescaffold will load it.

You can check it from console:

```
Jquery.const_defined?('Ui')
ActiveScaffold::Bridges::DatePicker.jquery_ui_included?
ActiveScaffold::Bridges::DatePicker.install?
ActiveScaffold.exclude_bridges.exclude? :date_picker

YourController.active_scaffold_config.columns[:date_column].form_ui
```

Just change controller and column name to check form ui element for desired column, it should be :date_picker.

Comment: Ok I have updated my question with responses of the commands you gave me. Please suggest how to fix this.

Comment: Have you tried last command? I do not see that in updated post.

Comment: Hmm it seems that ActiveScaffold uses date picker for that field, which version of jquery-ui-rails and jquery-rails gems are you using? are you included them to your application.js file ?

Comment: I only have jquery-rails in my gemfile: gem 'jquery-rails', '2.1.4'

Comment: Can you try to upgrade to newer versions of jquery-rails and add jquert-ui-rails (those two is now separated, from version 3.0) and also you can check similar issues to yours [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/activescaffold/NvHYHD9wRWc/jt0fWa--gm4J).